# Applying PhD during the last year of master studies

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, europe

I am a final year master student and currently I am working in my thesis (I have done about 70% of my work).  My graduation will be expected to be latest in this August.

I have published several publications during my bachelor degree.  However, I have not published any single publication during my master studies (my supervisor has a plan to publish a paper based on my thesis works).

Is it possible for me to apply for a PhD studies with stated condition above (I haven't get master degree and lack of publication in my master degree.

In addition  I do my bachelor and master thesis in different subfield. I will plan to take a PhD in the same subfield as my master studies. So I can say I dont have any publications directly related to my planned PhD studies.

Comment: It is certainly the right time to be applying. Don't delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely apply. If not now, then when?

The number of publications doesn't matter that much because the number is just a number; it doesn't reflect the complexity or difficulty of the research you did. I would fully expect that the publication resulting from your Masters studies will be more substantial - i.e., involve more work, with more robust results - than those you did during your Bachelor's.

If it still troubles you, remember there are people who do PhD studies without having published any papers in the past,